# Не работает запрос к MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Имеется запрос из JpaRepository

```
@Query("select cur from Currency cur where cur.date >= ?1 and cur.date <= ?2 and cur.basic_Title_Currency = ?3 and cur.quoted_Title_Currency = ?4")
    TreeSet<Currency> findByDateGreaterThanEqualAndDateLessThanEqualAndBasicTitleCurrencyAndQuotedTitleCurrenc(
            String dateAfter, String dateBefore, String basicTitleCurrency, String quotedTitleCurrency);
```

Выскакивает ошибка

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.TreeSet ru.kitosins.sibsutis.currency.repository.CurrencyRepository.findByDateGreaterThanEqualAndDateLessThanEqualAndBasicTitleCurrencyAndQuotedTitleCurrenc(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: basic_Title_Currency of: ru.kitosins.sibsutis.currency.entity.Currency [select cur from ru.kitosins.sibsutis.currency.entity.Currency cur where cur.date >= ?1 and cur.date <= ?2 and cur.basic_Title_Currency = ?3 and cur.quoted_Title_Currency = ?4]
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: basic_Title_Currency of: ru.kitosins.sibsutis.currency.entity.Currency [select cur from ru.kitosins.sibsutis.currency.entity.Currency cur where cur.date >= ?1 and cur.date <= ?2 and cur.basic_Title_Currency = ?3 and cur.quoted_Title_Currency = ?4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У аннотации `Query` есть параметр `nativeQuery`, который по-умолчанию равен `false`. Соответственно вы должны указать `JPQL` запрос, т.е. в запросе использовать поля сущности, а не поля таблицы (`basicTitleCurrency=?3`), либо уже указать `nativeQuery=true`.